# What does the # symbol mean in a TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For example, if I have this class:

```js
type Url: string;

class A {
   #url: Url
}
```

What does the `#` symbol do/represent? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [ECMAScript private field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields), new in TypeScript 3.8. The field can be accessed from methods inside the class, but cannot be accessed from outside the class.

More info:

- [TypeScript 3.8 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#ecmascript-private-fields)
- [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/)

Example from the documentation:

> ```
> class Animal {
>     #name: string;
>     constructor(theName: string) { this.#name = theName; }
> }
>
> new Animal("Cat").#name; // Property '#name' is not accessible outside class 'Animal' because it has a private identifier.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [jtbandes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961053/8634147), TypeScript `private` class member keyword is just syntactic sugar, acting on the *type level* (TypeScript compiler). At *runtime*, a `private` class member is actually *public*. We can see it with a `Object.assign(this, { 
field: value })` inside the class that works with a TypeScript `private` field but not with a `#` *(EcmaScript private)* field.

TypeScript team needed to keep both syntaxes and both behaviours not to break existing TypeScript code bases. As developers, we can choose between both syntaxes:

- ECMAScript private is more strict but perhaps not yet supported enough. Perhaps to enforce public API or with a mix codebase JavaScript/TypeScript.
- TypeScript private is more usual, especially because it's the same syntax as in Java and C#. It's enough for now for a full TypeScript codebase not public. But as the purpose of TypeScript is to converge toward ECMAScript, it may be a good habit to take now to use this new syntax.